# Waiting for POST request to finish before GET request starts (React/Node)

Tags: reactjs, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have been trying for ages to fix this myself but I have given up. I am using React and Node to:

1. Send text from React to Node
2. Modify the text in Node
3. Send the modified text back to React

It all works fine if I click to start the POST request, wait a second, then click a different button to start the GET request, but I am trying to do it all from one command. My problem is that the GET request often finishes first, so my question is: **How do I make sure the POST request finishes before the GET request starts.**

I have tried this, but to no avail:

```
  postReq = () => {
    if(this.state.theUrl.length > 0) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/check', {
      url: this.state.theUrl
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log("Success")
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)});
    }
    else {
      return 1;
    }
    return "Finished"
  }
  
  getReq = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:5000/check')
      .then((getResponse) => {
        this.setState({summaryParts: getResponse.data, postResponse: ""})});
  };

   callApi = async() => {
         const result = await this.postReq();
           this.getReq();
      }
```

Comment: can you share what `postReq` looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having `await` before `get` request.

```
callApi = async () => {
  const result = await this.postReq();
  await this.getReq();
};
```

Additionally, you need to update your `postReq` method as well, in order to `await` for the axios call returns with resolved promise. Otherwise, `return Finished` will be called before finishing the post request. (Therefore use `async/await` for `postReq` as well)

```
postReq = async () => {
  if (this.state.theUrl.length > 0) {
    /* await for the request to be finished */
    await axios 
      .post("http://localhost:5000/check", {
        url: this.state.theUrl,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Success");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
  return "Finished";
};
```

Comment: It worked! I fully understand where I was going wrong after reading your explanation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

add async and return

```
postReq = async () => {
if(this.state.theUrl.length > 0) {
return axios.post('http://localhost:5000/check', {
  url: this.state.theUrl
}).then(function(response) {
....
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.